# nginx wildcard domain mapping to another domain without changing URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have setup a server for wildcard domain mapping to desired url as below.

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name             *.example.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    return                  301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The above code works fine but the sub-domain urls are changing to **example.com**.Say for example,

```
**s1.example.com** is changing to **example.com**
**s2.example.com** is changing to **example.com**
***.example.com** is changing to **example.com**
```

My requirement is, ***.example.com** should be redirected to **example.com** but the url should remain same as ***.example.com**.Like,

```
**s1.example.com** url should be **s1.example.com**
**s2.example.com** url should be **s2.example.com**
***.example.com** url should be ***.example.com**
```

but the page should load from **example.com**

Please someone give a solution.

Thanks

Comment: The `return` **will** change the browser's address bar, that is what it does. Is `example.com` hosted externally or on the same machine?

Comment: example.com is hosted on the same machine.

Comment: Rather than add a new `server` block. You could add `*.example.com` to the `server_name` of `example.com`.

Comment: After adding ***.example.com** near the server name of **example.com** ,still,the URL in address bar changes to **example.com**.

Answer (score 0):

Chaning server_name in main server block from **example.com** to **.example.com** and adding subdomain ssl certificates to the main server block resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).